# Gerar classe C# a partir de um XSD

Tags: c#, xsd, xml-schema

Estou precisando gerar a classe a partir de um arquivo .XSD.

Apesar de já ter tentando de tudo que conhecia **(usado ferramenta do .net: xsd.exe, httputility.net e outros geradores de .cs)** não tive sucesso.

Creio que o erro está no schema que me passaram, mas não consigo idetificar qual o problema. Alguém pode ajudar? Desde já agradeço.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema targetNamespace="http://www.cnj.jus.br/replicacao-nacional"
elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:cnj="http://www.cnj.jus.br/intercomunicacao-2.2.2" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">

<import schemaLocation="http://www.cnj.jus.br/images/dti/Comite_Gestao_TIC/Modelo_Nacional_Interoperabilidade/versao_07_07_2014/intercomunicacao-2.2.2.xsd"
    namespace="http://www.cnj.jus.br/intercomunicacao-2.2.2"></import>

<element name="processos">
    <complexType>
        <sequence>
            <element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="processo" type="cnj:tipoProcessoJudicial" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</element>
</schema>
```

Comment: Executei seu código no site http://www.httputility.net/xsd-to-csharp-vb-class.aspx e veja o que erro que deu: Type 'http://www.cnj.jus.br/intercomunicacao-2.2.2:tipoProcessoJudicial' is not declared. Seu xsd está incompleto.

Comment: Esta linha de comando pode ser usada para gerar as Classes, tendo os Schemas da NF-e: Veja https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/218780/5704

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o seguinte:

- Salve o arquivo `xsd` (`http://www.cnj.jus.br/images/dti/Comite_Gestao_TIC/Modelo_Nacional_Interoperabilidade/versao_07_07_2014/intercomunicacao-2.2.2.xsd`) no seu compudador.
- Edite o arquivo e remova primeira linha `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` e salve.
- Agora já pode utilizar o arquivo para gerar a `classe`.

Veja parte do arquivo gerado:

```
namespace AutoGeneratedCode
{

   /// 
   [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34283")]
   [System.SerializableAttribute()]
   [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
   [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.cnj.jus.br/intercomunicacao-2.2.2")]
   [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://www.cnj.jus.br/intercomunicacao-2.2.2", IsNullable=true)]
   public partial class tipoEndereco
   {
      private string logradouroField;
      private string numeroField;
      private string complementoField;
      private string bairroField;
      private string cidadeField;
      private string estadoField;
      private string paisField;
      private string cepField;
      ///
```